# How to select a textbox in a webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I made a program that opens a Google Translate window when F1 is pressed.

I want the "source" textbox to get selected (focused on)

I tried this:

```
            formMain.Activate();

            formMain.panelMain.Enabled = false;
            formMain.panelMain.Focus();
            formMain.panelMain.Select();
            formMain.panelMain.Enabled = true;

           formMain.webBrowserMain.BringToFront();


            formMain.webBrowserMain.Select();
            formMain.webBrowserMain.Focus();

            formMain.ActiveControl = formMain.webBrowserMain;


 if (formMain. WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    Program.DoMouseClick((uint)formMain.PointToScreen(formMain. webBrowserMain.Location).X + 10, (uint)formMain.PointToScreen(formMain.webBrowserMain.Location).Y + 10);
                }




            HtmlElement textArea = formMain.webBrowserMain.Document.GetElementById("source");

            if (textArea != null)
            {
                textArea.Focus();
            }
```

But it only sometimes gets selected!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : 
This includes injecting custom Js in the site and calling that function , works for me in a similar case (Always do operations on a webpage after it has completed rendered/loaded):

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
         WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
                IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                element.text = "function trig_focus() { document.getElementById(\"theIdOfInputBox\").focus(); }";
                head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("trig_focus");
            }
```

Comment: Thx, can this get rid needing the computer generated mouse click?

Comment: I don't think this would trigger a mouse click event , does it ?

Comment: I tried setting focus to the textbox as seen above but I needed to fake a mouse click on my Windows form (it's a Windows Forms App) after these things in order to always succeed to focus on the textbox, your code says to focus on the textbox just like mine, but I still needed to fake a mouse click, how sure are you if I use your code I won't need to fake a mouse click on my form to ensure focus in the web browser in the form always?

Comment: I'm testing it.

Comment: For others: I added using mshtml; and Project-> Add reference to it.

Comment: It didn't work it's not selecting the textbox always, as bringing the window to front and focusing on it, if I don't fake a click with the mouse it doesn't select it.